# Is it possible to build a streamlit app with a matlab back end?

Tags: python, matlab, streamlit

No code - just requested for a project to build a tool with matlab code and wondering if i can use Matlab code as the backend for a Streamlit app?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, no. You could possibly set up MATLAB to work as an API of sorts to the Streamlit app using FastAPI in Python, but there is no out-of-the-box support for creating a Streamlit UI over MATLAB.

Comment: Thank you! i am unfamiliary with FastAPI but about how involved a process do you think this would be?